# Ubuntu One for Android and Fedora

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, client

1. I wonder where can I get ubuntu-one for fedora, any suggestions?
2. I want to sync my tablets (Android HoneyComb 3) with movies/pictures/music in my ubuntu-one account, is it possible? (I am not talking about ubuntu-one music)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you said Ubuntu one for fedora, did you meant the Ubuntu one Control Panel, if you meant that, then there isn't one that I know of, but if you really want it, then try using the Ubuntu one for Windows in Fedora through wine.
2. There isn't a app for Ubuntu one in Android HoneyComb yet, but I'm pretty sure the Tablet can access the Ubuntu one website, I not sure about download document to the tablet, but you should try.

Comment: I wanted an end to end solution, Ill go with asuswebstorage. thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. About installing ubuntu one on Fedora maybe you can try this tutorial http://www.pacificsimplicity.ca/blog/ubuntu-one-fedora-16-howto
2. There is an ubuntu one app for android. If you have problems download it from Google Play (now I think is not a problem anymore), you can allways download from other markets like aptoide